How to get access Uri or Path of file in AndroidI
In my application I want use ScreenRecorder and for this I used this library : https://github.com/HBiSoft/HBRecorder . 
I want when finished the screen recorder, upload that to server. 
I write below codes, but show me error. 
My Codes: 
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            _binding = ActivityCompressUploadBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
            //File uri
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                videoData.getVideoPath.collect { storedPath ->
                    if (storedPath.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        fileUri = if (SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.Q) FILE_URI else FILE_PATH?.convertFileToUri()
                        testId = TEST_ID
                        testTitle = TEST_TITLE
                        //videoData.saveVideoPath(fileUri.toString())
                    } else {
                        fileUri = Uri.parse(storedPath)
                        videoData.getVideoInfo.collect { info ->
                            if (info.isNullOrEmpty().not()) {
                                val infoSplit = info?.split(SPLITTER)!!
                                testId = infoSplit[0].toInt()
                                testTitle = "${infoSplit[1]} $testId"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                delay(300)
                val inputStream: InputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(fileUri!!)!!
                val file = File.createTempFile("video", ".mp4")
                inputStream.use { input ->
                    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                    input.copyTo(outputStream)
                }
    
                fileUri?.let { uri ->
                    val parcelFile = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r", null)
                    val inputStream = FileInputStream(parcelFile!!.fileDescriptor)
    
                    val file = File(cacheDir, contentResolver.getFileName(uri) ?: "temp_video.mp4")
    
                    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                    inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
                    outputStream.close()
                    inputStream.close()
    
                    if (file.exists() && file.length() > 0) {
                        val fileName = URLEncoder.encode(file.name, "UTF-8")
                        val progressRequest = ProgressRequestBody(file, "multipart/form-data") { progress ->
                            runOnUiThread {
                                binding.apply {
                                    uploadProgress.progress = progress
                                    uploadPercentageTxt.text = "$progress%"
                                }
                            }
                        }
    
                        val filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", fileName, progressRequest)
                        bodyUpload.file = filePart
    
                        videoData.saveVideoPath(uri.toString())
                        viewModel.callPostUploadVideoNew(testId, bodyUpload)
    
                        Log.e("FilePathLog", "File: ${file.path} --- Name : $fileName")
                    } else {
                        Log.e("FileError", "File was not created or is empty")
                    }
                }
    
            }
        }

private fun ContentResolver.getFileName(uri: Uri): String { 
   var name = ""
   val returnCursor = query(uri, null, null, null, null)
   if (returnCursor != null) {
      val nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
      returnCursor.moveToFirst()    
      name = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)
      returnCursor.close()
   } 
   return name
}


Error message: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.myapp/cache (Is a directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:308)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:238)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:180)
at com.testady.ui.compress_upload.CompressUploadActivity$onCreate$2.invokeSuspend(CompressUploadActivity.kt:167)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:235)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:168)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:474)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:508)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:497)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeUndispatched(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:595)
at kotlinx.coroutines.android.HandlerContext$scheduleResumeAfterDelay$$inlined$Runnable$1.run(Runnable.kt:19)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException

How can I fix it? 
I searched it into google and stackoverflow, but not found anything!

Off the cuff, it would appear that contentResolver.getFileName(uri) is returning the empty string.

@CommonsWare My codes for this extension function : private fun ContentResolver.getFileName(uri: Uri): String {         var name = ""         val returnCursor = query(uri, null, null, null, null)         if (returnCursor != null) {             val nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)             returnCursor.moveToFirst()             name = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)             returnCursor.close()         }         return name     }

There is no requirement for a ContentProvider to support the OpenableColumns. You have some scary code for getting the Uri, apparently referring to hard-coded values like FILE_URI and FILE_PATH.

@MohammadTellFa Don't add additional question code in to a comment, it makes it very unreadable. If there is addition information about the question edit the question instead. I hopefully have correctly edited your question to correctly move the private function in your comment to the question for you.
